# Passing sensitive data to Firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, encryption-asymmetric

I want to pass the user's password to a cloud function to do stuff with through an HTTP cloud function. I was thinking about using RSA encrytion with a private key stored in the index.js file used for writing cloud functions and the public key being included in the client side javascript. I found a library for RSA encryption and decryption in javascript (https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt). Could I import this into the cloud functions index.js file by just importing it or would I need to paste the contents into the cloud functions index.js file?

I'm not very knowledgeable about encryption, so I really don't know if this method would even make sense.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to protect against? Keep in mind that traffic between the client and Google Cloud Functions is already sent over a secured (HTTPS/TLS) connection.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen what if protecting something like database password from devs with lower access?